# задачи крон на хостинге с cpanel

Tags: python, cron

Есть небольшой раборчий скрип на питоне для отправки тестового письма. В общем ниже код

```
import smtplib                                      
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart      
from email.mime.text import MIMEText                
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage              

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '******'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
addr_to   = "*********"                  


msg = MIMEMultipart()                               # Создаем сообщение
msg['From']    = EMAIL_HOST_USER                          # Адресат
msg['To']      = addr_to                            # Получатель
msg['Subject'] = 'Тема сообщения'                   # Тема сообщения

body = "Текст сообщения"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))                 # Добавляем в сообщение текст

server = smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT)           # Создаем объект SMTP
server.set_debuglevel(True)                         # Включаем режим отладки - если отчет не нужен, строку можно закомментировать
server.starttls()                                   # Начинаем шифрованный обмен по TLS
server.login(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)                   # Получаем доступ
server.send_message(msg)                            # Отправляем сообщение
server.quit()
```

хочу запускать его на хостинге с помощью cron.В cpanel есть в стартовой странице ссылка на создание задачи. Ниже настройки которые я ввожу, но задание не выполняется. В ошибках тоже ничего не видно
На хостинге в терминале скрипт запускаю после активации виртуального окружения. Может в этом проблема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `запускаю после активации виртуального окружения` — делаете это вы, вероятно, выполняя что-нибудь вроде `$ source /какой-то/путь/activate`. вот и подставьте в ваш скрипт в качестве [шебанга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шебанг_(Unix)) `#!/какой-то/путь/python`. или вызывайте скрипт, указывая путь к интерпретатору явно: `$ /какой-то/путь/python /путь/к/вашему/скрипту`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать в поле "команда" путь до интерпретатора. Например так /usr/bin/python <путь к скрипту>
Если это не поможет, попробуйте использовать python3
Ах, да, забыл задать уточняющий вопрос. Доступ к серверу через ssh имеется? Пробовали проверять работоспособность скрипта в терминале?

Comment: да , скрипт в терминале запускал. /usr/bin/python тоже пробовал. Ничего не работало